# Unable to draw Road Polyline OSMBonus

Tags: c#, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Hi Am trying to Draw a polyline Overlay on OSM map using osm bonuspack,but am getting Type COnversion Error here

```
Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.BuildRoadOverlay(road, context);
```

Error: Cannot implicitly covert type OSMDROID.Bonuspack.overlays.polyline to osdroid.api.Polyline.

Please suggest whats wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

osdroid.api.Polyline is only used for the Google Maps api wrapper. Just change the cast to org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Ployline

Comment: org.osmdroid.views.overlay doesnt contain definition for polyline, do i need to match versions here.? Also i tried with org.osmdroid.views.overlay.PathOverlay and getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Just import the correct Polyline in your file:

```
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Polyline;
```

(instead of osdroid.api.Polyline)

Comment: org.osmdroid.views.overlay doesnt contain definition for polyline, do i need to match versions here.? Also i tried with org.osmdroid.views.overlay.PathOverlay and getting the same error. FYI  Am using Xamarin component

Comment: Polyline is part of osmdroid since V5.2.

Comment: Thank you, but the "getRoad()" function tries to connect to OSRM Server at router.project-osrm.org, can i customize it to my own hosted server .? As traffic to router-project is not best practices as per OSM.

Comment: Of course you can: use setService (and look in the javadoc, it's explained).

Comment: I wanted to know if is it possible to convert Server replied LineString to LineRing or a Polygon